# Simple SQL approach to transform columns into rows (SQL Server 2005 or 2008)

Tags: sql-server

On SQL Server, executing the following SQL Statement:

```
SELECT 1,2,3
```

will return

```
(no column name) (no column name) (no column name)
1                2                3
```

Note that the columns don't have names and the number of columns is not definite (it can have 1 column or it can also have > 100 columns).

My question is - **Does anybody know of a simple approach so I can get the following result**:

```
(no column name)
1
2
3
```

What I'm really trying to do is come up with a SQL similar to the one below. I wish I could execute it as it is but of course we know that the *Select 1,2,3* won't work, we have to somehow transform that into a table with the values in each row.

```
SELECT * 
FROM NORTHWIND.DBO.CUSTOMERS
WHERE EMPLOYEEID IN (*Select 1,2,3*);  -- *Select 1,2,3 will not work
```

Currently I'm thinking of creating a **user defined function** that returns a table by iterating through each column and dynamically creating multiple SQL statements combined by UNION similar to: `SELECT 1 Col1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3.` I'm not a fan of dynamic SQL and looping procedures in my queries as it can be expensive to process especially for an application with expected usage of 1000+ per minute. Also, there is that concern for SQL Injection Attacks with Dynamic SQL when I start using strings instead of integer values. I'm also trying to avoid temporary tables as it can even be more expensive to process.

Any ideas? Can we use **UNPIVOT** without the need for looping through the indefinite number of columns and dynamically creating the SQL text to execute it and transform the columnar values into rows? What about **Common Table Expressions**?

Comment: Are the values constant or from a sub-query that needs unpivoting? i.e are you asking for a briefer select 1 union all select 2 ...

Comment: See [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

Comment: the values will be provided as comma delimited integers passed as a string to the SQL Parameter object from C# and ADO.Net. (See my additional comments that I just added under Brian's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the select and just specify a list of values:

```
SELECT * FROM NORTHWIND.DBO.CUSTOMERS
WHERE EMPLOYEEID IN (1,2,3);
```

Comment: Brian, I apologize. I should have been more clear on my question. What I'm doing is passing the SQL Statement (with parameter names) along with the SQL parameter objects from C# to ADO.Net Command Object. The SQL will be like 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID in (@MULTIVALUE)". It will be nice if I can just assign the value of '1,2,3' to the SQLparameter object for @MultiValue but I can't. I'm trying different ways to do this without concatenating SQL text.

Comment: After thinking about this again. I did started going down the slippery slope of dynamic and concatenated SQL statements to find a workaround for providing values to the EMPLOYEEID IN (@MULTIVALUE) expression. Using table expressions instead of having a comma delimited list of values will still require me to concatenate parts of the SQL statements. If I'm going to do this, I might as well dynamically write the '(1,2,3)' and concatenate it with the SQL Statements.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 has better support for passing such parameters. http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html